# ng change and ng select not working

Tags: angularjs

So first the ng change is not triggering the search function. And the ng selected also no selecting the id = 0 option, is putting a blank option instead of selecting option 1. This is all contain the same in app and same controller.

Any ideas?

Code here

```
<select ng-model="OrderBy" ng-change="Search(true)">
  <option ng-repeat="x in OrderByList" value="{{x.ID}}" 
  ng-selected="{{ x.ID == 0 }}">{{x.Name}}</option>
</select>

$scope.OrderByList = [
               { Name: "option1", ID: 0 },
               { Name: "option2", ID: 2 }
    ];    

$scope.Search = function (x) {
    // Code
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you could setup a plnkr it could shed some light over your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), it'll probably work better for you.

```
<select 
    ng-model="OrderBy" 
    ng-change="Search(true)" 
    ng-options="x.ID as x.Name for x in OrderByList">
</select>
```

This will probably fix both issues.

In your controller do this:

```
$scope.OrderBy = 0;
```

Comment: In the OP, if I give `x.ID == 2` it is working. But not for 0. Any idea why?

Comment: okay, now the ng change works, but i'm still getting a blank option. When i change the blank option despairs.

Comment: I added in the other thing you need to do if you want the default to be 0. Set the OrderBy to 0